# Porque no se ejecuta la velocidad de mi Servomotor - Arduino desde Python

Tags: python, arduino

No comprendo porque cuando le envio una señal desde python al serial del arduino, el servomotor no gira. Solo funciona cuando no hay FOR.
Y si le envio el valor cad=1 directamente por el serial del arduino, tampoco gira.

Aqui le dejo los codigos de Arduino:

```
#include <Servo.h>  //Include the Servo Library
int opc,pos;
String cad;  
Servo servo1;   // "Servos" objects are created

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  servo1.attach(5,600,2500);
  //servo1.write(90);
}
void loop() {

if (Serial.available()) {    // Read the value sent by the Serial Port
  delay(5);
  cad=Serial.readString();
  opc=cad.toInt();
  if(opc=1){
      for(pos=88;pos<=90;pos+=1){    //Cuando coloco FOR no gira el servo
        servo1.write(pos);           //En lugar, si coloco directamente un valor en pos (ejem:180) 
                                     //si gira de acuerdo cuando Python envia opc=1
        }
   Serial.println(opc);
    
}
}}
```

He colocado pos=88 a 90 porque busco un movimiento lento del servo.
Y tambien tengo problemas al darle un giro igual de lento en sentido contrario.

Muchas gracias